# Windows 7 (Ultimate 64bit) + Virtual PC (XP Sp3) + PCI Parallelport Card + Parallelport Dongle

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc, parallel-port, dongle

I got a *Windows 7 64-bit* computer with an "XP-mode"-Virtual PC. I installed a *PCI parallel port card* and all drivers. The card is correctly installed under Windows 7. In Virtual PC however the card does not show up. I have to use an old parallel port *dongle* in the VM.

I searched Google about the problem and found some pictures likes this:

[image: link text]

However in my Virtual PC there is no LTP1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed VMware instead. Not it works....